# Node.js: реализовать загрузчик фотографий

Tags: node.js, jquery, fileupload, загрузка, express

Подскажите в какую сторону копать, может есть что то подобное:
Необходимо реализовать загрузчик фотографий:

1. При выборе фотографии она отображается на странице.
2. Отображение процесса загрузки при клике загрузить
3. После загрузки отображение загруженного изображения

Может быть кто подскажет загрузчик.
Крутил jquery file upload, вроде бы все есть и все хорошо, но что то не нравится он мне.
Не откажусь и если придется писать самому, будет уроком, да и практика не помешает (наверное это будет лучше чем готовое использовать), единственное пока неопределенность в том что именно нужно для всего этого.

Comment: Писать самому, ну вы оптимист :] Если вам не нужна тотальная кроссбарузерность, берите, хорошее коробочное решение.

Comment: RubaXa, ну если бы не был оптимистом, так бы до сих пор на заводе колобашки перекидывал с пакета в пакет xD
Ну на счет кроссбраузерности, да, для меня это 100% проблема. Ну а из готовы решений какие варианты есть?

Comment: Класс! Есть на что поглядеть и поюзать. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- http://fineuploader.com/
- http://www.plupload.com/
- http://mailru.github.io/FileAPI/ и на базе его http://rubaxa.github.io/jquery.fileapi/

Answer (score 0):

3.Я пользуюсь примерно таким вариантом [FileReader.readAsDataURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader.readAsDataURL),
примерно так:

```
var preview = document.querySelector('#previewPhoto');
var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onloadend = function() {
    preview.src = reader.result;
}

if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    $scope.file = file;
} else {
    preview.src = "";
}
```